# Using charCodeAt() to retrieve character from KeyCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, keyboard-shortcuts, keycode

I am trying to write a Javascript/jQuery function that will automatically bind keyboard shortcuts to my webpage. The method I have in mind is something like the following:

1. Loop through all elements with a class beginning with 'key-'
2. For each of these elements, retrieve the key combinations from the class, e.g. 'key-ctrl-s' will return <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
3. Bind the event for the combination of these particular keys to the document

Pretty basic algorithm, or so I thought... ***issue coming...***

So for example, I can enter the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="some_other_class ctrl+s">Save</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="ctrl+shift+s">Save As</a>
```

The above code will generate the following keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

And when these keys are pressed, the `click` event will be triggered for the relevant html element...

### The Issue

As stated above, the algorithm here is pretty darn simple, however, as usual, the problem comes when trying to write it.

I cannot see how I am going to know which keycode (`e.which`) to listen for when automatically binding the event.

***For example:***

Using the above HTML and the following jQuery, we can get thus far (ignore things like the regex):

```
function keyboardShortcuts(){
    // Loop through all elements with a class containing 'key-'
    $("[class*='key-']").each(function(){
        // Using a regular expression here, separate the class into individual keys
        // whilst ignoring other classes and the 'key-' prefix
        var keys = $(this).attr('class').match(/REGEX HERE/);

        // THIS IS WHERE THE CODE GETS A LITTLE MESSY
        // I AM VERY UNSURE ABOUT THE FOLLOWING

        // Define all special characters and set them to false
        var ctrl = false, alt = false, shift = false;

        // First test for special characters
        // Test for ctrl key
        if(keys.indexOf('ctrl')!=-1){
            ctrl = true;
            // Remove ctrl from the keys array
            keys.splice(keys.indexOf('ctrl'),1)
        }
        // Test for alt key
        if(keys.indexOf('alt')!=-1){
            alt = true;
            // Remove alt from the keys array
            keys.splice(keys.indexOf('alt'),1)
        }
        // Test for shift key
        if(keys.indexOf('shift')!=-1){
            shift = true;
            // Remove shift from the keys array
            keys.splice(keys.indexOf('shift'),1)
        }

        // Determine special characters to test for
        if(ctrl&&alt&&shift){

            // Bind the keypress event to the document

            $(document).keypress(function(e) {
                if((e.ctrlKey||e.metaKey)&&e.altKey&&shiftKey) {

                    var continue = true;

                    // Test for other characters in keys array
                    for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){

                        // THIS IS WHAT I AM REALLY UNSURE ABOUT
                        if(keys.indexOf(charCodeAt(e.which))==-1){
                            // Correct key was not pressed so do not continue
                            continue = false;
                        }
                    }

                    if(continue){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        // Proceed to triggering the click event
                        // No more help needed from here...
                    }
                }
                return true;
            });
        }else if(ctrl&&alt){

        }else if(ctrl&&shift){

        }else if(shift&&alt){

        }else if(ctrl){

        }else if(alt){

        }else if(shift){

        }
    });
}
```

As you can see from the above, the code is quite long winded, but I simply cannot see another way of writing it... Other than maybe a few tidy ups with arrays here and there, but even so the nested if statements are pretty much a necessity aren't they?

### Finally, My Question

Excluding the fact that the code is pretty untidy and could probably be written a little/a lot better (if you do have views on this please provide them), my actual question is in reference to the line that reads:

```
keys.indexOf(charCodeAt(e.which))==-1
```

Is this a reliable method of retrieving the character from the character code across all browsers? If not, is there a better way to do it?

Anybody that has any opinions on the rest of the code, please post, would love to have some feedback.

Comment: An interesting problem.  From my experimentation in Chrome, you don't actually receive keypress events for non-printable characters like ctl+s.  But you *can* receive keyup and keydown events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I got started on this, I didn't intend to rewrite the whole thing.  But I did, and you can see it working at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slashingweapon/mhvCc/).

The technique is to find all of the target elements and build a list of what key combinations each one maps to.  We store these in the array `keybindings`, and every time someone presses a key we look through the whole list looking for a match.  If we find one, we trigger a click event on the element.

I used `keydown` instead of `keypress` because you actually get the modifier information with it.  I also improved the class string parsing, but it could be made a little cleaner I'm sure.

Here's the JS code.

```
var keybindings = [];

$('[class*="key-"]').each(function (idx, val) {
    var keyspec = {
        which: 0,
        altKey: false,
        shiftKey: false,
        ctrlKey: false,
        element: val
    };

    var keystring = $(val).attr('class').toLowerCase();
    var match = /key-\S+/.exec(keystring);
    var parts = match.toString().split('-');
    keyspec.which = parts[ parts.length-1 ].toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0);
    for (var jdx in parts) {
        if (parts[jdx] == 'alt') keyspec.altKey = true;
        else if (parts[jdx] == 'shift') keyspec.shiftKey = true;
        else if (parts[jdx] == 'ctrl') keyspec.ctrlKey = true;
    }
    keybindings.push( keyspec );
});

$(document).keydown( function(evt) {
    $.each(keybindings, function(idx, oneBind) {
       if (evt.which == oneBind.which
           && evt.altKey == oneBind.altKey
           && evt.shiftKey == oneBind.shiftKey
           && evt.ctrlKey == oneBind.ctrlKey)
           $(oneBind.element).click();
    });
});
```

Of course it occurs to me now that there's probably a jquery plug-in for this already and we could just use that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will have a good read through and come back if I have any issues. Much appreciated, thanks again :-) +1

Comment: Got it to work brilliantly with a few minor tweaks. Thank you very much, much better method than the one I suggested! :-)